# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on Kafka Consumer with spring-kafka 2.1.0 and SpringBoot 1.5.9

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to setup Kafka Consumer using SpringBoot(1.5.9) and Spring-kafka(2.1.0). However when I start my app I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V on Kafka MessagingMessageListenerAdapter. I tried with Spring-Kafka(1.2.0) and that error went away. Has anyone else experienced this version incompatibility?

Here is my config class

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ImporterConfigs{

static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ImporterConfigs.class);

@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private static String bootstrapServers;

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerKafkaConfigs() {
  Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
  // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kakfa cluster
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
  // allows a pool of processes to divide the work of consuming and processing records
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-group");

  return props;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
  return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerKafkaConfigs());
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());


  return factory;
}
```

}

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.determineInferredType(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:396) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:100) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListenerInstance(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:172) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListener(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:132) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupMessageListener(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:338) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:323) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:227) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:49) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:183) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:155) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:129) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:138) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:132) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:229) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at com.vitechinc.springbootapplication.V3MessageImporterApplication.main(V3MessageImporterApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: you are not providing any code examples that we could run to help you.

Comment: @ramrunner The question is more about the version compatibility and not code

Comment: nice edit. it makes it conform to site standards.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Spring-kafka `2.1` is based on the Spring Framework `5.0` and that is exactly what you see with that error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)
```

Spring Framework `4.3` (the foundation for Spring Boot `1.5`) doesn't support Java 8 yet.

You should consider to switch to Spring Boot `2.0` or stick with the Spring Kafka `1.3.2` which is compatible with Boot `1.5` background and can be reconfigured for Apache Kafka `1.0` Client.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I wanted to confirm

Comment: weird, because they're stating that Spring Framework 4.3.x supports JDK 6-8
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions

Comment: That’s right, you can use any Java you need, but the framework code base can’t use language features higher than 6 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a weird **maven version mismatch** between the mvn used by IntelliJ (invalid/old version -> deprecated /.m2/repository) and mvn on the commandline (3.9.0)