# How to use Spring Kafka 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

It is really great to grab the **Spring Kafka 2.1.0.RELEASE**  to unleash the power of the **kafka client 1.0.0**. However when I tried to use it **spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE** , which is the latest release version of boot it throws an exception .

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.determineInferredType(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:396) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:100) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
```

My POM file is

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

...

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

.....

How should I be able to use Spring Kafka 2.1.0.RELEASE with a spring boot project .

Is there any release of boot that support spring 5 yet.

Thanks 
Joy

Comment: Sure there is. Check http://start.spring.io/ (currently 2.0.0.M7). Okay it's not a "release" technically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on Kafka Consumer with spring-kafka 2.1.0 and SpringBoot 1.5.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912241/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-on-kafka-consumer-with-spring-kafka-2-1-0-and-spring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Answer

Click [disqus.com](https://disqus.com/by/feojeda/?utm_source=digest&utm_content=comment_author&utm_medium=email)

This is beautifully explained by Francisco , I put up the link as it might help others as well!

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE` and `spring-kafka:2.1.0.RELEASE` have faced similar but not this exception, I would suggest cleaning and building application again to clear maven cache and dependencies.